# Helm 'if' condition in one line

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I was trying to put the `if` condition in a single line of the helm template:

```
- name: ENV_VARIABLE
  value: {{- if .Values.condition }}"Value1"{{- else }}"Value2"{{- end }}
```

However, I'm getting error:

> Error: YAML parse error on chart/templates/deployment.yaml: error
> converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line NN: could not find expected ':'

So I've ended up with multi-line condition:

```
- name: ENV_VARIABLE
{{- if .Values.condition }}
  value: "Value1"
{{- else }}
  value: "Value2"
{{- end }}
```

which is working fine, but is very uncompact.

Is there a way to use one-liner `if` condition in helm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you do works, but you use the leading hyphen, which [removes all preceding whitespace](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Text_and_spaces).

The below will render as `value:foo` due to the hyphen.

```
value: {{- "foo" }}
```

If you remove the hyphen, it should work.

That said, there is also the [ternary function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html) which could fit here.

> #### ternary
>
> The ternary function takes two values, and a test value. If the test value is true, the first value will be returned. If the test value is empty, the second value will be returned. This is similar to the c ternary operator.
>
> ##### true test value
>
> `ternary "foo" "bar" true`
> or
>
> `true | ternary "foo" "bar"`

```yaml
- name: ENV_VARIABLE
  value: {{ .Values.condition | ternary "value1" "value2" | quote }}
```